# Constraintlayout overlap views

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I currently have 2 cardlayout, one below the other. Each card contains a constraint layout (and each one contains its own child). These 2 cards are inside a main constraint layout.
I've put the second card (called main card) below the first one (called info card).
The problem is that the main card overlap the info card, and I don't know why. Below the screen:
[image: views overlapping]

And this is my XML file about these 2 views:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/constraintlayout_sendaudio_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/backgroundColor">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview_sendaudio_info"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout_sendaudio_info"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        .. Its child

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardview_sendaudio_maincard"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardview_sendaudio_info">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintlayout_sendaudio_maincard"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        .. Its child

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the '+' from the following line:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardview_sendaudio_info">
```

instead have:

```
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cardview_sendaudio_info"
```

You add the + sign when you create and name a new view. You don't need it when you're referencing an existing view.

Comment: Probably yes. However I deleted all constraints and recreated it. It solved the problem probably because the problem you found. Thank you

Comment: it's an easy mistake to make, especially if you're copying+pasting